# Setting Up Sublime Text with XDebug (windows 7 environment)

Tags: php, laravel-4, sublimetext2, xdebug

I'm attempting to set up xdebug with Sublime Text 2 and I'm having some issues getting it to work.

I'm doing this on a Windows 7 environment using xampp, so setting up XDebug was simply a matter of configuring it in the php.ini file.  Below are my config settings:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 8000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

I'm using laravel 4 for my framework.

I installed the xdebug plugin for sublime: https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug

I believe that this is set up properly.  I can set breakpoints etc.

In sublime i created a project in the root directory of my laravel project and edit the *.sublime-project file as follows:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "/C/****/****/****/sites/questionairre/"
                    //this is the root of my project folder
    }
],
"settings":
{
    "xdebug":
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000"
    }
}
```

}

Now that that is out of the way, I'll typically set a breakpoint, and then start to debug.  4 windows open: "Xdebug Context", "Xdebug Watch", "Xdebug Stack", "Xdebug Breakpoint".  However, my default browser does not open.  Is something configured wrong?

Thanks for reading through this long message.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but in case it helps someone...

In terms of getting the browser to open I set `"url": "http://localhost/index.php"` i.e with `index.php` included in the path and the browser then launches when *Start Debugging (Launch Browser)* is clicked.